# What's the function of `'` in `printf "%x" "'你"`?

Tags: linux, bash, printf

I want to get the hexadecimal value of `你`, someone tell me to use `printf "%x" "'你"`, but I don't know what's the function of `'` in `printf "%x" "'你"`, why use `'` before `你`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the bash manual:

> Arguments to non-string format specifiers are treated as C constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character.

`%x` is a numeric specifier, not a string one, so this section applies. The documentation is a bit wrong (or outdated) when it speaks about ASCII values, but it's correct in spirit: an argument of `'你` evaluates to the numerical value of the unicode codepoint `你` (without the quote, it would be a syntax error, since 你 isn't a number). The codepoint value that it evaluates to is then formatted in hexadecimal by `%x`.